# How to scale procedural texture?

Tags: procedural, shader-nodes

I try to make the right side texture turn to left side texture with procedural node. Is it possible?

[image]

[image]

Comment: in the title you ask for scaling, then in text: right side texture turn to left side texture, what do you want now? scale or rotate your texture?

Comment: I guess he wants the effect we see on the left, i.e. dots that gradually reduce

Comment: ah...yeah, that sounds reasonable

Comment: moonboots is right. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere along the line, you need a per-row Y index.. you could do that by subtracting a per-cell UV from an overall UV at the same scale.

But to save nodes, this version cheats by using the ready-made `[distance from cell centre]` and `[position of cell centre]` provided by a non-random Voronoi texture...

[image]

The scale-per-row is animated by keying the 'To Max' field of the *Map Range* node..

[image]

If you're not cheating, you would break the UV space up yourself.

[image]

- Here, starting with the 'Generated' coodinates, always 0-1 in all
  dimensions of the shaded object's bounding box.
- The *Multiply Add* node  **a)** scales the coordinates, so they run from 0-4 in X and Y, and **b)** shifts the coordinates, so they run from -0.5 to 3.5. .. 'Raw Space'
- The *Wrap* breaks the -0.5 to 3.5 range into 4 cells in each direction of -.5 to +0.5 .. 'Cell UV'
- If you subtract the 'Cell UV' from the 'Raw Space', each cell is shaded with the location of its center, in 'Raw Space' coordinates. That is, from (0,0) to (3,3) across the piece. .. 'Cell Idx'.

Below, see 'Raw Space'/3, 'Cell UV', and 'Cell Idx'/3:

[image]

You can use the Y of 'Cell Idx' to tell the shader which row of cells you are in, and use that to influence any attribute of your UV-based procedural pattern, per row.

Below, a procedural pattern produces an outlined star from the local Cell UV. Its 'r' (radius) attribute is set by a mapping of the row that it's in:

[image]

.. with this result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you talk more about the first method you mentioned above? Actually I want to do the same thing with different shapes.

Comment: Hi, @saS ! Sure thing. See edit.